# Small fitting outerwear

Tags: clothing

I'm a smaller guy (5'7"/125lbs) and I always have difficulty finding clothes. I'm currently looking for some type of down/synthetic filled layer to go ice climbing in. My main issue is a men's small leaves 5-7" of extra air space in the middle of my back and a women's size is too tight on my shoulders.

I'm in Eastern Canada, so ordering from a company that allows my to ship something back for a return is definitely a requirement for me.

I have a good soft-shell and heavy winter coat, but I'm needing something in between.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try any of the following that come in XS:

1. Outdoor Research "Neoplume Jacket"
2. North Face "Super Zephyrus"
3. Patagonia "Nano Puff"

Outdoor research has a good return policy I have dealt with them before.  North Face has lifetime warranties and accepts returns, conveniently at retail locations even if purchased online. Also take a good look at [**MEC**](http://www.mec.ca/Main/home.jsp) they have a great return policy and are a Canadian Co-op, they have great sales and mostly free shipping, if not it is very reasonably priced.

**Alternatively**, you could try layering and use your soft shell such as: Base layer+merino+fleece+softshell.  It won't be as light/compact/warm as a single 60g Primaloft One Mid-Layer but it's worth a shot in my opinion.  Play around with it and who knows you might find something that works for you!

Comment: I looked at OR and North Face's websites for those and they don't come in XS. MEC has been somewhat helpful but tends to not make XS's. Luckily, there's a Patagonia store nearby I can try the Nano Puff

Comment: @Miles Sorry, the Super Zephyrus does come in XS but only in US you may be able to source it adn Outdoor Research is already preparing for their Fall 2014 lines and seem to be out of stock of everything.

Comment: @Miles also check out, http://www.altitude-sports.com/en, they have amazing sales and also offer free shipping within Canada! wooo, just picked up an Arc'teryx Atom LT for 180$